# Ignore special characters with lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to create a lucene search index for a bunch of names. I want to be able to search the names neglecting the case, umlauts, special chars, whitespaces and so on.

Ideally, querying for `Robert` or `Rober Roberts` should match `R'obert Röbertson`.

Which Analyzers or Filters to I have to apply in `apache lucene` to achieve this?

So far I'm using `new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9)`, but that is tied to exact matches.

And moreover: how can I chain analyzers? Because an IndexWriter only takes a single analyzer:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9);
new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_9, analyzer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possibly a standard way of doing this, but all I can think of is storing a 'sanitized' version in a special (different) field with something like this:

```
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(string, Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
```

or just straight up removing special characters with regex:

```
String normalized = string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "");
```

and then adding the normalized field to the index:

```
    final Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new Field("fieldName", normalized, Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED));
```

in doing this, your normal content would still be the same, but lucene will be able to search the normalized field as well

**UPDATE**

Ok, so for the normalisation you are going to need multiple steps, first removing diacritical and then special characters:

```
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(string, Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
        .replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]+", ""); // <-- note the space
```

So for input `R'obert Röbertson`, the above returns `Robert Robertson`